# In PHP, how to destroy session and close the window?

Tags: php, javascript, html, window

I want to close the tab as well as destroy the sessions in the php.

I have this piece of code, but doesn't work well.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>

<script language="javascript"> 

setTimeout("self.close();",10000) 

</script>
```

Help through,
Thanks.

Edit: It doesn't close the window as expected.

Comment: My bad, it doesn't close the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function openWin()
{
myWindow=window.open("","","width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}

function closeWin()
{
myWindow.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have tried to use firefox browser to test

In firefox, You can only close window via JavaScript that have been open via a script window.open() call.

Please refer the below link

[Close firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/942157)

Try Internet explorer.

Comment: Is the javascript enabled? How you're accessing through a web server or local disk? Which version of IE it is?

Comment: The java script is enabled, I'm using IE 10. I'm accessing Localhost which is WAMP.